# Why Is `data(“kendogrid”)` Undefined?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm a starter in kendo.ui, I've written this code to create kendo.ui.grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BrandViewModel>(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.BrandName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.BrandAbbr);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SrcImage);

        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("editItem"));

    })

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("CustomCommand_Read", "Brand"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
    )
)
```

When the user clicks the edit button in grid it will show Edit view in kendo.ui.window and the user can edit data.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window().Name("Details")
    .Title("Customer Details")
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Height(400)
    .Draggable(true)
    .Width(300)
    .Events(events => events.Close("onClose"))
)

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div id="details-container">
        <!-- this will be the content of the popup -->
        BrandName: <input type='text' value='#= BrandName #' />
    </div>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
    var windowObject;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        windowObject = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");
    });

    function editItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        windowObject.refresh({
            url: "/Brand/Edit/" + dataItem.Id
        });
        windowObject.center().open();
    }

    function onClose(e) {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

    }

</script>
```

but in `onClose` method `$("#Grid").data("kendoGrid")` is Undefined, please help me, thanks all

Comment: totally random guess... after .Name("Grid") and .ID("Grid")

Comment: @ Robert Levy : ID is Undefined property in kendo.ui.grid.

Comment: Are you sure that $('#Grid').length returns > 0?

Comment: Add `debugger;` to your onClose() method, then try $('#Grid') in the console, making sure that comes back with the element you expect. Then try $('#Grid').data() in the console. Continue to debug in this manner.

Comment: @ Timothy Walters:When I run the first and click in Edit button grid refresh but when I click again on a new record for editing when close popup window $('#Grid') is Undefined.

Comment: I think your window is in a frame, so it is a different page, try getting all grids with $(".k-grid"), if it is empty (length==0) then no grids. Or try to put the grid pointer in a global var

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I have the same problem atm :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try Window load event

```
$(window).load(function () {
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
```

this work for me.

Comment: $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource._data

Answer (score 0):

var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid"); //call grid by Name of Grid you used in razor