# Kendo Grid How to Trigger add new row by external button?

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have simple kendo grid.

I would like to trigger create, save, etc buttons with external buttons outside of the grid columns.

See image for more informations.

How can i do it in Kendo Grid please?

Thanks for any advice. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this, For Add new item in grid,

```
 $('#btnAddCard').on('click', function () {
    $('.k-grid-add').trigger('click');
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can trigger adding a new line to a kendo grid with a button using a clickfunction:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" id="yourButtonId"></a>
```

And then simply:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var grid = $("#yourGridNameHere").data("kendoGrid");
    $("#yourButtonId").click(function () {
        grid.addRow();
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you! But for some reason the grid object was undefined when it was set in the $(document).ready event, but I was able to get around this problem by using the $(window).load event as suggested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22984437/1179865